# Destructing partial object to a new object in js

Tags: javascript

Given the following object `{a:1, b:2, c:3}` I'm looking for es6 syntax to distruct a subset of the object to a new one i.e: `{b:2 ,c:3}`.

I've found this syntax enabling me to omit the properties I don't want:
`const {a,...newObj} = original`.

How can I do it, with including the properties names.

Comment: Object spread/rest is not a part of the language yet, it will probably be included in ES 2018 though. There's not a easy syntax to do it.

Comment: Cool, but I'm working with Babel

Comment: @RoniGadot your `Const {a,...newObj} = original` works fine. Do you want to achieve something else. Please explain

Comment: It works, but I want to cherry pick the fields I want and not omit the ones I don't

Comment: @RoniGadot, added my answer according to your requirement. Please let me know in case of some problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cherry pick the properties you want like shown below. The name of the new variable should be same as the property name. Then you can create a new object containing those picked properties.

```js
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
var {b, c} = obj;//pick property b and c
var newObj = {b, c}; //shortcut for {b:b, c:c} in ES-6
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 10):

One of the following single liners will do the job -

Using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
// if keys are guaranteed to exist in `obj` use:
Object.fromEntries(['key1', 'key2'].map((k) => [k, obj[k]]));
    
// if keys might not exist in `obj` use:
Object.fromEntries( Object.entries(obj).filter(([k]) => ['key1', 'key2'].includes(k)) );
```

Using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
// if keys are guaranteed to exist in `obj` use:
Object.assign({}, ...(['key1', 'key2'].map((k) => ({[k]: obj[k]}))));

// if keys might not exist in `obj` use:
Object.assign({}, ...(['key1', 'key2'].filter(k => obj.hasOwnProperty(k)).map((k) => ({[k]: obj[k]}))));
```

Using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
( ({key1, key2}) => ({ key1, key2 }) )(obj);
```

The above allows getting a new object without creating intermediate variables or objects.

For example -

```js
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
var newObj = Object.fromEntries(['a', 'b'].map((k) => [k, obj[k]]));
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you really want. But as far as I understood this will help you.

For example

I have the initial object

```
{ a: 10, b: 20, c: 100 }
```

Properties I want to extract are **a, b**

And I want to create new object **c** with property **b, c**

Here is how it is done. Using destructive assignment. Here the out put will be **20** as in the initial object.

```js
({ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 100 });
let c = {a: a, b: b};
console.log(c.b);
```

MDN Document to destructive assignment. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

If you switch from vanilla Javascript to its superset Typescript, this will become a bit easier. I've made couple of functions for this kind of purposes:

To filter selected fields, from an object. You can use following:

```js
/**
 * Return a subset object of the source object containing only listed fields 
 * @param source Source object
 * @param fields List of source object's fields to be included in a returning object 
 */
export const subset = <T>(source: T, ...fields: (keyof T)[]): Partial<T> => {
  return fields.reduce((prev, field) => ({
    ...prev,
    [field]: source[field],
  }), {});
};
```

To make filtering by listing fields to be excluded use following:

```
/**
 * Return a subset object of the source object with listed fields excluded 
 * @param source Source object
 * @param fields List of source object's fields to be included in a returning object 
 */
export const exclude = <T>(source: T, ...fields: (keyof T)[]): Partial<T> => {
  const result: Partial<T> = { ...source, };
  fields.forEach(field => delete result[field]);
  return result;
};
```